# How to configure pylint / python to check for MicroPython syntax?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylint, micropython

I'm using VScode to write MicroPython code.
The linting and code completion is quite decent, but as there are quite a few differences between CPython and MicroPython, I think it could be better.

Is there a way for pylint to :

- recognize the [micropython standard libs and modules](https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/library/index.html#python-standard-libraries-and-micro-libraries)
- recognize the subset of classes / methods implemented versus CPython

In other words I'd like to prevent errors and warnings such as these:

[image: warnings]

I've looked at a promising approach by Thonny to extract module information and save that in [module/APIstubs](https://github.com/thonny/thonny/tree/master/thonny/plugins/micropython/api_stubs), and extend that to more complete prototypes. However that would still require pylint to include and prioritize these over CPython.

Is that something that can be configured in pylint and/or Python, and if so, how would I go about that?

**Update :**
I have a decent partial solution on https://github.com/Josverl/micropython-stubber and there also may be interest to solve this more generally in vscode

Comment: What if you added the stubs directory to PYTHONPATH of pylint process?

Comment: I gave that a try by adding `init-hook='import sys; sys.path.insert(1,"C:\\Develop\\thonny\\thonny\\plugins\\micropython\\api_stubs\\")'` to `.pylintrc`, and that does work to a degree.
1. the '[pylint]' errors change, apparently the stubs picked up , but are not correct yet ( missing returns type , parameters etc) 
2. the `[Python]` warnings however, are unaffected

Comment: Alternately, set the python.linting.pylintPath to an appropriate version of Pylint for the Python interpreter being used.

Comment: @JosVerlinde there probably isn't one for MicroPython yet. However this question would probably reach the best audience on the [MicroPython forum](https://forum.micropython.org/index.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to achieve this a few things are needed:

- Stub files for the native / enabled modules in the firmware using PEP 484 Type Hints
- Specific configuration of the VSCode Python extensions
- Specific configuration of Pylint
- Suppression of warnings that collide with the MicroPython principals or code optimization.

A detailed explanation can be found in:
https://github.com/Josverl/micropython-stubber#boost-micropython-productivity-in-vscode

If you do not want to generate and gather the subs yourself, common MicroPython stubs stored in the sister-repo: https://github.com/Josverl/micropython-stubs